# SQL Server 2008 Create Trigger after insert... return id... called stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I just want a SIMPLE sql server trigger (after insert) to get the ID back from the table that was inserted into...  So algorithm:

1. new record is inserted into table
2. trigger is called
3. trigger takes id from inserted record and called stored procedure

My failed attempt is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insertNewMarket] 
   ON  [dbo].[markets]
   AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @marketID int
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SELECT ID from inserted
    --set @marketID = Inserted.ID--get the inserted id and pass to stored proc
    exec marketInsert @marketID 
END
GO
```

Comment: SELECT @marketID = ID from inserted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In trigger, you can access an table with the name "[INSERTED](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8f622138-2e8a-45f9-9987-b4d8f26c4d34/after-insert-trigger-question-how-to-use-value-from-last-added-record?forum=transactsql)", which will have the newly inserted record details. small example below

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insertNewMarket]   
   ON  [dbo].[markets]  
   AFTER insert  
AS   
BEGIN  
    declare @marketID int  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT @marketID = ID from inserted  
    exec marketInsert @marketID   
END  
GO
```